# Bi-directional polymophic relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Infoset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :infosetable,  :polymorphic => true
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :productset
  has_one :infoset, :as => :infosetable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Productset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :infoset, :as => :infosetable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products
end
```

I can get infosets fine via `Product.infoset` or `Productset.infoset`

But how do I get a `Product` or `Productset` via `Infoset`?

`infoset.product` just returns the infoset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@infoset.infosetable` will return either a Product or a Productset, as appropriate.

Comment: I just get method_missing when I try that.

Comment: Wait... I think I'm having a stupid attack. Tried it again and it seemed to work..

Comment: I was trying to call infosetable on a collection. Derp. `infoset = Infoset.where(:usp_sku => params[:usp_sku]) infoset.infosetable`